# Repeat print of a pattern repeated n times in one line with sed

Tags: sed, gnu

With a `sed` cmd I want to print all occurrences of a pattern in one line.
I know how to do this with `grep -Pe` and with `awk`. I started with:

```
$ sed 's/^.*label="\(.*\)" selected.*$/\1/g' <(echo 'smkj sld/6_ !label="snd 1" selected>lms slks.;label="snd 2" selected>lkwnl  wlkmlabel="snd 3" selected>The following should not be printedlabel="')
snd 3
```

However the above only prints `snd 3`, i.e. the string between the **last** occurrence of `label="` and `" selected`.  How do I include all occurrences of the regex on any one line ?

Comment: Are you parsing an XML document? What does that document look like and what data do you need to extract from it in what format?

Comment: `sed` always matches the longest match for `^.*label="`. That is why the last "label" is printed and everything else gets substituted. `sed` is simply not the right tool to do that job.

Comment: Yes, maybe you missed that. From [gnu sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html): "Note that the regular expression matcher is greedy, i.e., matches are attempted from left to right and, if two or more matches are possible starting at the same character, it selects the longest."

Comment: @Kusalananda: No XML here at all.  The data looks completely unstructured. It only has those two tags `label` and `selected` as shown.

Comment: I think it's pretty much universally true with regular expression implementations that the `*`, `+`, `{n,m}` quantifiers are all greedy. Some implementations have non-greedy equivalents `*?`, `+?`, `{n,m}?` but certainly not all.

Comment: I would use `grep -oP '(?<=label=").*?(?=")'` myself.

Comment: KIndly post input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GNU sed` we can generate the desired output as shown below:

```
$ sed -Ee '
     s/label="([^"]+)" selected[>]/\n\1\n/
     s/.*\n(.*\n)/\1/
     /\n/!d
     P;D
' input.txt
```

Outputs:

```
snd 1
snd 2
snd 3
```

With `Perl` you can do it as a one liner:

```
$ perl -lne 'print for /label="([^"]+)" selected[>]/g' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '$/.join("\n").put if m:g/ label\= \" <(<-["]>+)> \" \h selected \> /;'  <(printf 'smkj sld/6_ !label="snd 1" selected>lms slks.;label="snd 2" selected>lkwnl  wlkmlabel="snd 3" selected>The following should not be printedlabel="')
snd 1
snd 2
snd 3

#OR

~$ raku -ne '$/.join("\n").put if m:g/ label\= \" <(<-[\c[QUOTATION MARK]]>+)> \" \h selected \> /;'  <(printf 'smkj sld/6_ !label="snd 1" selected>lms slks.;label="snd 2" selected>lkwnl  wlkmlabel="snd 3" selected>The following should not be printedlabel="')
snd 1
snd 2
snd 3
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family, and this answer is intended to compliment the excellent Perl answer posted by @RakeshSharma.

Briefly, this Raku answer takes the same approach as @RakeshSharma: instead of trying to solve the problem using 'frugal-vs-greedy' matching, recognize that your target string surrounded by quotation-marks is devoid of internal quotation-marks. Thus (akin to @RakeshSharma), in Raku you declare a custom **negative** character class with `<-["]>+`, which translates to *"one-or-more characters in-a-row devoid of `"` the quotation-mark character*. (In case you're wondering, `<+[…]>` or more simply `<[…]>` denotes a custom **positive** character class). The second answer explicitly uses the canonical `\c[QUOTATION MARK]` name, which can sometimes help circumvent thorny quoting issues.

Then the remainder of the Regex is as follows:

- The desired match is preceded by `label\= \"`
- The desired match is followed by `\" \h selected \>` (`\h` stands for horizontal whitespace).
- After the entire regex is matched, Raku's `<( … )>` **capture markers** drop everything outside.

Raku's `$/` variable contains the final match, and because a `m:global/ … /` or `m:g/ … /` match was specified, the desired three matches are returned.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org